# Непонятное поведение background-image. Наследование

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, наследование

Доброго времени суток! Верстаю header. Разбит он на 3 секции.В свою очередь, каждая секция разбита на 3 фигуры. В каждой секции должен быть свой `background` из чего формируется картинка, фигуры без `background`. 
Я решил поверстать по методологии "наследование"(возможно есть другие названия). И вот сразу же проблема - `background` ведет себя не ожидаемо. 
`background` первой секции применяется не к ней, а к родителю (к header). А `background` остальных 2-х секций не применяются.

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#header .section{
width: 33%;
border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
#header:first-child {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/56/hamburger-576419__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% 20%;
}
#header:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/40/steak-575806__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}
#header:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/12/cup-156743__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}

#header:first-child .widget{
 width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50%;
}

#header:first-child .widget:first-child{
  /*background: none;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
<section class="section">
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
</section>
<section class="section">
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
</section>
<section class="section">
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
</section>
</header>
```

Во всех учебниках указывают, что псевдокласс `:first-child` пишется без пробела. Но я решил поставить пробел. В итоге, `background` первой секции стал как нужно, но при этом, все первые элементы секций (фигуры) наследовали этот `background`. Ниже 2-й вариант кода, с пробелом, перед псевдоклассом

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#header .section{
width: 33%;
border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
#header :first-child {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/56/hamburger-576419__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% 20%;
}
#header:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/40/steak-575806__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}
#header:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/12/cup-156743__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}

#header:first-child .widget{
 width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50%;
}

#header:first-child .widget:first-child{
  /*background: none;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
<section class="section">
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
</section>
<section class="section">
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
</section>
<section class="section">
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
 <figure class="widget"></figure>
</section>
</header>
```

Как быть? Я совсем запутался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробел ставить не нужно,ошибка в селекторах(последний специально оставил каскадом чтобы было понятнее)

```
.section:first-child {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/56/hamburger-576419__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% 20%;
}
.section:nth-child(2)  {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/40/steak-575806__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}
#header .section:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/12/cup-156743__340.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}
```

Comment: Мне бэкграунды не нужны в фигурах. Бэкграунд нужен в секциях. (первых потомках хедера)

Comment: @Дмытрык  #header .section:first-child

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо. Но понять все равно не могу -
 почему так.Переоформите ответ - приму.